# How to test for fluoride levels in drinking water?

Tags: water

I would like to test for fluoride levels in the water.

Are there any methods or test kits available to test the levels of fluoride in home water supply?

See also: [Is there any at home test for fluoride levels in your water, and what is the best water distillation unit?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110824093408AA5tigC)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good reliable set-up is pricey.  [Here's a link](http://www.hach.com/intellical-isef121-fluoride-ion-selective-electrode-ise-1-meter-cable/product?id=7640513803) to a reliable, quality probe for fluoride ion detection in water, it costs \$740  (US).  [The meter](http://www.hach.com/hq30d-portable-ph-conductivity-optical-dissolved-oxygen-do-orp-and-ise-multi-parameter-meter/product?id=7640494072) that it plugs into sells for \$790 (US) if you get the less expensive hand-held device.  There also manuals and instructions on how to actually use the gear, at the website as well.